How do I make my X and O symbols show up in a Tic Tac Toe game in C#?
I'm trying to create a tic-tac-toe game. I managed to create an empty board and ask for user input, but my symbols aren't showing up on the board.
private class Player
{
    public  bool IsSquareTaken { get => GetsSquareAndVerifies(); }
    public char Symbol { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }

    // creates a player and gives them a symbol
    public Player(char symbol)
    {
        Symbol = symbol;
    }
    public Player()
    {

    }

    public bool GetsSquareAndVerifies()
    {

        TicTacToeGame game = new TicTacToeGame();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"It is {Symbol}'s turn.\nWhich square would you like to play in? (1-9)");
            if ((!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int userInput) || userInput < 1 || userInput > 9))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number!");
                return true;
                
            }
            Row = (userInput - 1) / 3;
            Column = (userInput - 1) % 3;

            if (game.Board[Row, Column] != '\0')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Halt! That square is taken.");
                return true;
            } else if (game.Board[Row, Column] == '\0')
            {
                game.Board[Row, Column] = Symbol;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

 private class TicTacToeGame
 {
     private char[,] board = new char[3, 3];
     Player player = new('X');
     Player player2 = new('O');
     public char[,] Board { get => board; set => board = value; }

     public void InitializeBoard()
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
             {
                 Board[i, j] = '\0';
             }
         }

         for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
         {

             Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}  ", Board[r, 0], Board[r, 1], Board[r, 2]);
             if (r < 2)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("----+----+-----");
             }
         }
     }

     public void DisplayPlacedSymbol()
     {
         while (true)
         {
            if (player.IsSquareTaken == false)
             {
                 for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
                 {

                     Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}  ", board[r, 0], board[r, 1], board[r, 2]);
                     if (r < 2)
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("----+----+-----");
                     }
                 }
                 Console.WriteLine($"Symbol {player.Symbol} is placed at {player.Row}, {player.Column}");
             }
            
             if (player2.IsSquareTaken == false)
             {
                 for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
                 {

                     Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}  ", board[r, 0], board[r, 1], board[r, 2]);
                     if (r < 2)
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("----+----+-----");
                     }
                 }
                 Console.WriteLine($"Symbol {player.Symbol} is placed at {player.Row}, {player.Column}");
             }
         }
     }
 }

  internal partial class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {

          TicTacToeGame game = new TicTacToeGame();
          game.InitializeBoard();
          game.DisplayPlacedSymbol();
      }
  }

I was expecting for the symbols to show up, and then I could fix any wacky formatting. Before, I was able to get the symbols to show up with no problem, but they would erase after each time I made a new move. After that, I made some changes to the functionality of my code by doing this code:
Row = (userInput - 1) / 3;
                Column = (userInput - 1) % 3;

Before that, it was a lot more messy with a lot of if else statements. I also used to have a seperate field for the UserSymbol and I printed that instead of board, but I thought it messed with me checking if the current square was empty... I'm really confused on what to do next. I want to fix this before moving onto victory, draw and loss code.

OT Tip: Instead of copying that code to print the board, move that to a DisplayBoard method and call that wherever you need it

In your Player,
   public bool GetsSquareAndVerifies()
        {

            TicTacToeGame game = new TicTacToeGame();
            // ...
            // verify and puts circle in game
        }

This means whenever a player inputs, you first generate a whole new TicTacToeGame, and then puts the input in that new instance. But, that is not the game in your Main(). Therefore, the game you're drawing is always empty, because you never put O or X in it, they're in other boards you generated in Player, and never is drawn.
You can reconsider about the class structure. For example, you're currently checking board status and changing the TicTacToeGame in a Player. However, a Player is a Player, it shouldn't directly change TicTacToeGame, but tell TicTacToeGame what it did, and let TicTacToeGame react.
Something alone the line of,
    // Add a currentPlayer in TicTacToeGame to track which player is it currently, then in the main loop controls the whole game's flow,

  while (true) {
    string input = game.AskForInput(); // TicTacToeBoard will go ask Player, e.g. currentPlayer.GetInput() - The Console.ReadLine() part now is in Player class.

    if (!game.Verify(input))
    {
      ShowErrorCellOccupied();
      continue;
    }

    game.PlaceSign(input); // use game.currentPlayer to know what sign it needs to place.
    game.SwitchPlayer();
  }

So Verify and PlaceSign is on TicTacToeGame to handle, and Player only needs to handle Input.
Have fun!

Thank you so much! Your tip was really helpful but also didn't give too much away. I was able to puzzle it out after your advice and make it work.

Sorry I was in a hurry so couldn't detail this out. Glad you solved it after all.

It's because you create a new instance of TicTacToeGame in each Player and don't use the main one whee you actually set the noughts & crosses.
You should pass through a reference of TicTacToeGame in the constructor of Player and initialise each player in the TicTacToeGame constructor:
private class Player
{
    private TicTacToeGame _game;

    // creates a player and gives them a symbol
    public Player(char symbol, TicTacToeGame game)
    {
        Symbol = symbol;
        _game = game;
    }
    
}

private class TicTacToeGame
{
    Player player;
    Player player2;

    public TicTacToeGame()
    {
        player = new('X', this);
        player2 = new('O', this);
    }
}

Please note: I removed the other code from the class for simplicity, you will still need your other class properties / members / methods etc.

On the implementation of the game itself:- Simply use sets as the abstract syntax representation of the game! Valid moves and winning moves are then just simple set expressions of the set of moves made by nought and/or the set of moves made by cross... The concrete syntax of the game, typically the board on which it is played, has little if anything to do with the abstract syntax of the game, except to capture it's usual user-representation. Simples, as it just means don't ever confuse concrete and abstract syntax... A really GOOD idea ):-)
